# How does activi handle concurent process variable modification?

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

Suppose there is multi-instance task, which assigned to 2 users. Every instance has `TaskListener` which modify process variables when task properies is updated. How does activit handle a situation when both listeners run together and try to modify same process variable? Does this mnodification threadsafe or not?

Answer (score 3):

Processes are executed inside DB transactions. If process (or its listeners) modifies process variables, they are stored/updated inside this transaction. Once aynchronous part of process ends, transaction is commited.

So if two process executions that work in parallel modify same variable, one of executions will commit transaction, but another one will fail on commit, that is after all work is done (generally engine throws optimistic locking Exception). Failed part will be re-run later by job executor, but it's better to avoid concurrent modifications.

If process executions modify different variables, they both can commit their transactions.

Activiti engine code is thread-safe. Also thread safety is mandatory for  listeners. If your code is not thread-safe, you should not use it in listener.